# Adding items to an aliased namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm using a namespace to switch between different versions of my database implementation. My client code should not need to know the details so I use a namespace alias to hide the specific version from the client code.

## db_v1.h

```
 namespace db_v1
 {
     class Database ...
 }
```

## db_def.h

```
 #ifdef _DB_V1
     #include "db_v1.h"
 #endif

 namespace db = db_v1;
```

Now if I want to extend the namespace with additional items, which are not version specific, I would like to add them to the namespace `db`, but the problem is that I can not use `namespace db` because it is an alias.

## db_global.h

```
namespace db   <-- should be using the namespace for the current version
{
    typedef enum
    {
         OK
    } value;
}
```

Obviously I get an error here because the namespace `db` already exists, while what I really want is, to extend the namespace without knowing wich version is the current one.

As far as I can see, I would have to put such a defintion into a separate namespace like `db_global` or I would have to duplicate such symbols in all versions, which I don't really like.

Is there some way to define it such that I can write in the client code something like:

```
 x = db::value::OK;
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach... Namespaces are used to avoid name collision, but what you probably need is to work with inheritance and polymorphism, keeping the same namespace... What is the problem in having a base class that setup all the basic functionality and let derived classes to define the exactly behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
#ifdef _DB_V1
    #include "db_v1.h"
#endif

namespace db {
    using namespace db_v1;
}
```

in `db_def.h` instead of `namespace db = db_v1;`? This way all contents of `db_v1` are imported into `db` namespace. Obviously, it may be conditionally-compiled:

```
namespace db {
#ifdef _DB_V1
    using namespace db_v1;
#elif defined _DB_V2
    using namespace db_v2;
#endif
}
```

For example, this code works well:

```
namespace db_v1 {
    void foo(){}
}

namespace db_v2 {
    void foo(){}
}

namespace db {
    using namespace db_v1;
}

namespace db {
    typedef enum
    {
         OK
    } value;
}
```

Comment: AHHHH! So simple! Yes, I was thinking about how to use `using`, but I was thinking in the wrong direction because I was so set on the alias. :) Thanks!